# Is there a closed expression for $\sum_{n =2}^{\infty}\pi(n)z^n$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, power-series, divisor-counting-function

Is there a closed expression for $\sum_{n =2}^{\infty}\pi(n)z^n$?
I mean, Is there a representation for this power series? Here $\pi(n)$ is the number of primes less or equal than $n$.

Comment: If there were then you could use differentiation to explicitly compute $\pi(n)$...seems unlikely.

Comment: But it would be rather inefficient. Differentiating an ugly function $10^{12}$ times is a **lot** of work.

Comment: By changing the order of summation we obtain $$\sum_n \pi(n)z^n = \sum_p \frac{z^p}{1-z}$$ and a closed form would be equivalent to a closed form of $\sum_p z^p$, which is a rather wild function.

Comment: The change of order of summation is just using $\pi(n) = \sum_{p \leqslant n} 1$, so $$\sum_n \pi(n)z^n = \sum_n \sum_{p \leqslant n} z^n = \sum_p \sum_{n \geqslant p} z^n = \sum_p \frac{z^p}{1-z}\,.$$

Comment: Related OEIS entries: [A000040](https://oeis.org/A000040) (prime numbers), [A000720](https://oeis.org/A000720) (prime counting function), [A010051](https://oeis.org/A010051) (characteristic function of the primes).